# "Winding number" of the map $g: T^{2n+1} \to U(N)$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, winding-number

For $n\in \mathbb Z_+$, let $T^{2n+1}$ be the torus and $U(N)$ be the unitary group, where $N$ is sufficiently large.

A physics paper on topological insulators claims the following:

> For a map $g: T^{2n+1} \to U(N)$, we can associate an integer-valued winding number defined as
> $$  \frac{(-1)^n n!}{(2n+1)!} \left(\frac{i}{2\pi}\right)^{n+1} \int_{T^{2n+1}} \mathrm{Tr}\left( (g^{-1} dg)^{2n+1}\right) \in \mathbb Z.$$

1. Why is it integer-valued?
2. How can we interpret the above quantity as the winding number? (The dimensions of $T^{2n+1}$ and $U(N)$ are different, but what I know from the de Rham cohomology theory is that the degree of map is defined for two connected and compact manifolds with the same dimension.)
3. Is the above invariant related to the fact that $\pi_{2n+1}(U(N)) \simeq \mathbb Z$? (The physics paper also mentions this fact, but not explicitly states how the above invariant is related to $\pi_{2n+1}(U(N))$.)
4. Is the above formula valid if we replace the domain of $g$ to $S^{2n+1}$?

Comment: At a glance, it looks to be more closely related with the homomorphism of cohomology groups $H^{2n+1}(g,\mathbb{Z}):H^{2n+1}(U(n),\mathbb{Z})\to H^{2n+1}(T^{2n+1},\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer to 1 and 4.

1. This formula is the right-hand side of the Atiyah-Singer index formula for the index of Toeplitz type operator on the torus obtained by restricting g to the positive spectral projection of the elliptic self-adjoint Dirac operator on $T^{2n+1}$ (the A-class is =1 in this case). Hence, this number is an integer.
2. The same is true for $\mathbb{S}^{2n+1}$.

Also 3. can be used to give a more direct proof of 4: the "winding number" is a homomorphism from the homotopy group of $U(N)$ to $\mathbb{C}$; the homotopy group in question has one generator; hence, it remains to check the integrality for the generator.